# Effective search with contains

Tags: c#, string, search, trie

I have a Trie data structure, it searches 100 000 elements in a blink of an eye. However it only searches words which start with the searched string, for example "Fi" will find "Final" but won't find "GooFi" and I want it to return "GooFi" too. That is why I am here asking you guys if this is the correct structure in this case. I implemented it myself, wrote unit tests so it's working so far. What I need is a hint how my goal can be achieved, I don't want anyone to write the code for me, that is not why I am here. Anyways here's my search implementation:

```
public List<string> Seach(string word)
{
    List<string> results = new List<string>();
    this.DoSearch(this.Root, 0, new StringBuilder(word), results);
    return results;
}

private void DoSearch(TrieNode currentNode, int currentPositionInWord, StringBuilder word, List<string> results)
{
    if (currentPositionInWord >= word.Length)
    {
        this.DfsForAllWords(currentNode, word, results);
        return;
    }

    char currentChar = word[currentPositionInWord];

    bool containsKey = currentNode.Children.ContainsKey(currentChar);
    if (containsKey)
    {
        if (currentPositionInWord == word.Length - 1)
        {
            results.Add(word.ToString());
        }

        TrieNode child = currentNode.Children[currentChar];
        this.DoSearch(child, ++currentPositionInWord, word, results);
    }
}

private void DfsForAllWords(TrieNode currentNode, StringBuilder word, List<string> results)
{
    foreach (var node in currentNode.Children.ToArray())
    {
        word.Append(node.Value.Value);
        if (node.Value.IsWord)
        {
            results.Add(word.ToString());
        }

        this.DfsForAllWords(node.Value, word, results);
        word.Length--;
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600292/high-performance-contains-search-in-list-of-strings-in-c-sharp?rq=1

Comment: For searching for a substring a trie gives no benefit over a plain list or array, as you have to check all strings. For some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299168/fast-filtering-of-a-string-collection-by-substring/1299211#1299211

Comment: What about suffix tree then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/gngeorgiev/Trie

Here is the repo of the Trie if anyone ever needs it. Supports prefix and substring search.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a kind of index over all nodes.

`Dictionary<char,List<TrieNode>> nodeIndex;`

Now if you want to search for example for "Fi" iterate over `nodeIndex` and search as before. In case you found something on that iteration you have to prepend the found substrings with the string leading to the actual node.

```
public List<string> Seach(string word)
{
    List<string> results = new List<string>();

    foreach(var node in nodeIndex[word[0]])
    {
        List<string> nodeResults = new List<string>();

        this.DoSearch(node, 0, new StringBuilder(word), nodeResults);

        foreach(var nodeResult in nodeResults)
        {
            var text = string.Format("{0}{1}",node.Parent.Text, nodeResult);
            results.Add(node.Parent.Text, nodeResult);
        }
    }

    return results.Distinct().ToList();
}
```

Maybe there are some yet missing properties you have to implement.

Comment: Thank you for posting, this came to my mind however it seems that this will waste memory as one of my goals is not to waste memory since I am going to work with a lot of data. Anyways I modified the Trie to search in a substring. I am going to post my code later so more people can benefit from it.